# Estimating the remainder of a converges series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Is there a way in general to estimate how fast the remainder of a convergent series decreases?

> Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, find how fast $\sum_{n=j}^\infty a_n$ decreases.

This is frequently needed in large number (probability theory) related problems. For example, in the proof of the strong law of large numbers, we need

1. $\sum_{n=j}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{O(1)}{j}$.

Another example is,

2. $\sum_{n=j}\frac{1}{n^{2/p}}=O(1)j^{(p-2)/p}$, $p\in(1,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try bounding series by integrals: if $f(x) > 0$ and $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x \ge N-1$,

$$ \int_{n=N-1}^\infty f(x)\; dx \ge \sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n) \ge \int_{n=N}^\infty f(x)\; dx$$

This is particularly useful for series $\sum_n n^p$ where $p > 1$ is constant.